# remove a required reviewer from Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

We have a gentleman who is no longer actively working on a project.
The problem is he is a required reviewer on our Pull Requests.

I have not been able to find a way to remove him, and we cannot complete our pull requests.

I have spent several hours looking at every option that I can find.

[image]

Update 10/10 -- We attempted to use the API and remove this reviewer and do another PR, but with no luck yet.
We have even tried having other reviewers approve, but without the other required one it just will not let us complete.
I would be happy to move this question as I know it is not code related, but don't know where to....this is not just a 'what tool do you think is best' question --- we are really in a bind here!

[image: second picture]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about code, it's about how to configure a specific tool.

Comment: Where would you suggest I move the question to @AndyLester?
This may not be code related, but it is a major issue for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the branch policy of the parent folder, I was having a similar issue but got resolve when disabling the policy for both the folders.

Comment: It has been resolved for quite a while now, but that is what I wound up doing.

Answer (score 7):

Check [Automatically include code reviewers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#automatically-include-code-reviewers) section under Branch policies:

`Repos >> Branches >> ... (at your branch) >> Branch policies >> Automatically include code reviewers`

If you have access to update them, just delete the unneeded reviewers. If you don't have access, take a look at Branch security, or find a person who has access.

I'm not sure if it will work for current Pull Request, maybe you will need to make it again.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help Anna.
We do not show any Automatic reviewers, and we tried using the API to remove the required reviewer with no luck yet.
We did try a new PR after that but with no change yet.
We are going to try creating a new branch next and will update this.

Comment: Sorry for that. Could you please share which API you tried? DELETE for Pull Request Reviewers? New branch should solve the problem

Comment: Yes, we tried the Delete for pull request reviewers (I think so at least) -- the programmer that did that is sleeping now and comes back online in about 4 hours.

Comment: It seems like there should be a way to see who is on the 'required' list of reviewers in the UI and modify it there.  The problem is this has a super critical bug fix held up that our users are currently lighting their torches and preparing to storm the castle if I don't get it out.

Answer (score 2):

> remove a required reviewer from Azure Devops

You need ask someone who has the permissions to `Edit policies` (`Project Administrators`) to remove that required reviewer from the `Automatically include code reviewers`:

[image]

**Note:** You need to check the Branch policies of the branch which you want to merge, for example, you merge from `Dev` to `master`, you need check the Branch policies of the `master` branch.

Then, after remove that required reviewer, you could go back to your pull request and click the `X` button:

[image]

Now, that required reviewer is no needed.

[image]

Hope this helps.